# install htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex

I need to convert a series of latex documents to a single html file. I would like to know how to install the htlatex program on fedora 31. I tried to install the tex4ht package without being able to. The latex2html program is not compatible with my latex codes.

Answer (score 3):

I use Fedora myself, but I don't use TeX Live provided by Fedora packaging. I use vanilla TeX Live from the TUG website, as it always gets the updates. Anyway, I can see that there are following packages in Fedora repositories:

- texlive-tex4ht
- texlive-make4ht

I am sure you will need also other packages from TeX Live, especially for LuaTeX. They should be installed as dependencies hopefully.

I am also sure you don't want to use `htlatex`, this command is obsolete. Use `make4ht` instead. [Here is the documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html) with reasons why you should use it.